# upgrade code from crm 4 to crm 5

Tags: dynamics-crm

am trying to upgrade code from ms crm 4 to crm 2011, but I have some issues...

where has `CrmService` and `MetadataService` class gone ?

tried to ref

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Metadata;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Client;
using Microsoft.Crm.Sdk;
```

Answer (score 2):

They are now bundled into one service called the `OrganizationService`.